# Using viewpoint to create tasks on exchange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exchangewebservices

Im using the viewpoint gem to connect to exchange via EWS, I've looked through the wiki (it's very limited) and can't find any reference as to I can (from the user im logged into), send a task to another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that EWS/OWA does not allow tasks to be assigned to other people.